# Replace/substitute characters for file renaming in Bash

Tags: bash, rename

I have the following filenames in a directory:

```
file_foo_01_2010.nc
file_foo_02_2010.nc
...
file_foo_12_2018.nc
```

and I'd like to rename all of them at once to:

```
file_foo_2010_01.nc
file_foo_2010_02.nc
...
file_foo_2018_12.nc
```

I understand that I could loop over each file in bash script and do it that way, but I was wondering if there is a more concise way to do it? Something like:

```
mv file_foo_12_201?.nc file_foo_201?_12.nc
```

to rename each December file etc.

I essentially want to switch characters 9-10 with 12-15 and am not sure on how to do this with bash. I am aware of `rename` but am not sure it can be used for my use case.

Comment: Not sure if the duplicate exactly answers my question? I tells you how to replace a string but not how to substitute characters like I require.

Comment: Yeah, it does. You want to use one of the tools that lets you use a regex, like "rename". You'll need to use two capture groups, one for each of the two numeric patterns.

Comment: Hmm.. OK. Having read all of the dupe question and answers, I'm still none the wiser and it's only thanks to the answer below that I have a solution. I knew that I had to use `rename` or similar but was struggling with understanding/how to do the 'capture groups' which the dupe answers do not fully explain.

Answer (score 1):

With the Perl's `rename`:

```
$ rename -n 's/(_[^_]+)(_[^_]+).nc$/$2$1.nc/' *.nc
rename(file_foo_01_2010.nc, file_foo_2010_01.nc)
rename(file_foo_12_2018.nc, file_foo_2018_12.nc)
```

Remove `-n` if you are satisfied with the result.

Comment: Thanks - worked for me. Could you please explain the `(_[^_]+)(_[^_]+)` part in your answer then I can accept?